# Put rows into list items based on matching 2 columns

Tags: r, pattern-matching, grouping, igraph

I need my dataframe put into items of a list so each potential person is in a 'bucket', based on 2 columns *ID* and *ID2_value*. Then I'll perform user validation manually to confirm same person or not.

multiple rows with the same *ID2_value* is potentially the same person - they need to be put together.
multiple rows with the same *ID* is definitely the same person.

```
fname_c1   ID         ID2    ID2_value   by    bm    bd   
  <fct>   <fct>      <fct>    <fct>     <int> <int> <int> 
1 STEFAN   100       MEDICAL#1  60        1957     9     2    
2 HANS     205       MEDICAL#1  60        1957     6     7    
3 PODRICK  104       MEDICAL#2  5003      1933     6     7   
4 BOB      600       MEDICAL#2  2005      1960     9     2    
5 PODRICK  104       MEDICAL#1  89        1933     9     2   
6 STEFAN   100       MEDICAL#2  1001      1957     6     1  
7 GARY     104       MEDICAL#4  AAB       1933     6     1    
8 GARY     110       MEDICAL#4  AAB       1933     6     1
```

From the above data, rows that should be put together are

```
fname_c1   ID         ID2    ID2_value   by    bm    bd 
  <fct>   <fct>      <fct>    <fct>     <int> <int> <int>  
1 STEFAN   100       MEDICAL#1  60        1957     9     2   
2 HANS     205       MEDICAL#1  60        1957     6     7   
3 STEFAN   100       MEDICAL#2  1001      1957     6     1   

fname_c1   ID         ID2    ID2_value   by    bm    bd   
4 BOB      600       MEDICAL#2  2005      1960     9     2   

fname_c1   ID         ID2    ID2_value   by    bm    bd   
5 PODRICK  104       MEDICAL#1  89        1933     9     2  
6 PODRICK  104       MEDICAL#2  5003      1933     6     7  
7 GARY     104       MEDICAL#4  AAB       1933     6     1  
8 GARY     110       MEDICAL#4  AAB       1933     6     1
```

I'm having trouble thinking about how to do this double matching.

## reproducible code

```
dat <- structure(list(fname_c1 = structure(c(5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L), 
                                           .Label = c("BOB", "GARY", "HANS", "PODRICK", "STEFAN"), 
                                           class = "factor"), 
                      ID = structure(c(1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L), 
                                     .Label = c("100", "104", "110", "205", "600"), 
                                     class = "factor"), 
                      ID2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), 
                                      .Label = c("MEDICAL#1", "MEDICAL#2", "MEDICAL#4"), 
                                      class = "factor"), 
                      ID2_value = structure(c(4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 6L), 
                                            .Label = c("1001", "2005", "5003", "60", "89", "AAB"), 
                                            class = "factor"), 
                      by = c(1957L, 1957L, 1933L, 1960L, 1933L, 1957L, 1933L, 1933L), 
                      bm = c(9L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 6L), 
                      bd = c(2L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                             "data.frame")
                      )
                 )

dat <- data.frame(dat)
library(tidyverse)
```

The below is matching both and only keeping the 'intersection'

```
batches_all <- dat %>% 
  group_split(fname_c1, ID2_value)
```

I'm looking for the union of both matches.

Comment: This is best conceptualized as a graph theory problem. Think of your original data as a graph where adjacencies are indicated by ID and ID2_values in the same row. The output you want is the nodes in each connected subgraph. I don't have time to answer now, but the `igraph` package has functions to make this quite simple.

Comment: cheers @Gregor I'll look into it